# Can I mass-download YouTube videos?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Been talking to Social Gnip, and looking at the Youtube Data API, but it looks like they just provide the the URL to the video.

Can I use something like youtube-dl to download all those videos? NOT store them, just analyze them and discard them.

Starting a computer vision project, and want to analyze YouTube videos to find products to identify influencers.

Comment: What language are you using to do this? Do you want to just get a list of video urls to download or do you want to download the videos through code?

Comment: Node, but could do python. Want to download the actual 480p .mp4 video file to run through computer vision algorithm, and want to download *lots* of videos.

Comment: Since you're using NodeJS, try using the [youtube-dl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl) npm package. With regard to mass-downloading try running multiple instance of that. But I think it would be better if you also write your own implementation.

Comment: Well duh haha I said I was using youtube-dl in the question. Just curious about rate-limiting or the legality of downloading a crap ton of videos from a single ip address.